# control number of options on select form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a php variable `$a` of int type. Now if `$a=1;` then first two options should only be visible, if `$a=2;` then first three options should only appear and so on. How can I achieve this?

```
echo "<form class='form-horizontal'>
        <fieldset  >   
            <span class='control-group' >
            <span  class='controls'>
                <select id='fl' class='form-control' style='cursor:pointer;'>
                    <option " . ($default == 0 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " style='display:none;' value='0'>Select</option>
                    <option " . ($default == 1 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " value='1'>Option1</option>
                    <option " . ($default == 2 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " value='2'>Option2</option>
                </select>

            </span>
        </span>
        <div><button id='mybtn' type='button'>Save</button></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place options in a variable based on `$a` value before the `echo` and use that variable in the `echo`

```
<?php
$options = '';

if($a==1)
{
    $options = "<option " . ($default == 0 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " style='display:none;' value='0'>Select</option>
                <option " . ($default == 1 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " value='1'>Option1</option>";
}
else if($a==2)
{
    $options = "<option " . ($default == 0 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " style='display:none;' value='0'>Select</option>
                <option " . ($default == 1 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " value='1'>Option1</option>
                <option " . ($default == 2 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " value='2'>Option2</option>";
}

echo "<form class='form-horizontal'>
        <fieldset  >   
            <span class='control-group' >
            <span  class='controls'>
                <select id='fl' class='form-control' style='cursor:pointer;'>
                    ".$options."
                </select>

            </span>
        </span>
        <div><button id='mybtn' type='button'>Save</button></div>
        </fieldset>

    </form>";
?>
```

Comment: thanks..that worked but after using your answer I came up with a slightly more elegant solution :if ($a>=1){echo "<option " . ($default == 1 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " value='1'>Option1</option>";if ($a>=2){echo "<option " . ($default == 1 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " value='2'>Option2</option>"; }}

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a perfect opportunity for a `for` loop.

```
// put your values into an array for easy access inside the loop
$options = array(
    1 => "Option1",
    2 => "Option2",
    3 => "Option3",
    etc...
);

// output the beginning of the <select> html
echo "<select id='fl' class='form-control' style='cursor:pointer;'>
         <option " . ($default == 0 ? "selected='selected'" : "") . " style='display:none;' value='0'>Select</option>";

// loop through items until we reach our limit, set in $a
for ($i = 1; $i < $a; $i++) {
    echo "<option " . ($default == $i ? "selected='selected' " : "") . "value='" . $i . "'>" . $options[i] . "</option>";
}

// output the end of the <select> html to close it off
echo "</select>"
```